# Picking a professional username for a custom domain email

Tags: professionalism, email

I have my own domain JohnSmith.com

what should I call my username for my email?

me@johnsmith.com
john@johnsmith.com
smith@johnsmith.com

This email will be used for resumes, so trying to make it look professional.

Comment: I would not use a domain name I paid for on a resume as you are going to get lots of spam.  Use a name you can trash after you get a job.

Comment: The good news is that since you have your own domain, you're not forced to add disambiguation to your username, so you have more choice. The advice in the linked question applies: keep it short and easy. "me" is awkward. "firstname@FirstnameLastname.com" is the most smooth unless you have a long first name.

Comment: As a side issue, a good question might be what is the current fashion with regard to domains of the form "FirstnameLastname.com"? I've heard the term "vanity domain" thrown around. Is having your own email domain now considered gauche?

Comment: @Frisbee, you can make it so google is your email provider with your own domain name. Last time I checked, it was $50/year.

Comment: @teego1967 $50 is not free and I still use a name I would just throw away.  It was just comment.

Comment: @Frisbee neither is having your own domain. For reliable email service (with tools to kill spam), however, google is great and worth the extra coin. "Throw away" emails look terrible.

Comment: @teego1967 Let it go.  It was a comment.  I don't have a question.

Comment: @Frisbee, whatever, I am just ironing out your non-sequitur comment.

Comment: @teego1967 Let it go.  A throw away name does not look terrible - you are not restricted to what can use in a throw away name. Google is not the only email service with spam protection.  And cost has nothing to do with the question.

Comment: Tlldr: If it isn't offensive or otherwise inherently troubling, nobody really cares what your e-mail address is.